# Arabic text is messed up HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website and I faced this problem; any Arabic text within `<h2>` is viewed like this:

[image]

Any Arabic text outside the `<h2>` tag is viewed correctly. Here is the CSS code for `<h2>`

```
.body h2 {
    direction: rtl;
    font:bold 24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#323a3f;
    padding:10px 5px;
    margin:5px 0 5px 0;
}
```

Any proposed solution. Thanks

Comment: Copy please a arabic word here.

Comment: For those of us who do not read Arabic, what's wrong with the h2 text?

Comment: Can you jsfiddle your situation?

Comment: I am not very good at Arabic however believe that the `direction: rtl;` is going to be your problem...

Comment: @AaronHatton, isn't Arabic normally written right-to-left?

Comment: The right text view is مشاريعنا so if you compare the both texts you will find the letters are viewed oppositely like this انعيراشم

Comment: @TomZych it is read right-to-left from my understanding not not written...

Comment: is the issue that it is **bold** ?

Comment: With or without the `direction:rtl;` the browser should recognise and display correctly the Arabic text.  The option should only affect the overall placement of the text (right aligned instead of left aligned) and the order of the words/sentences when you are mixing it with non-arabic letters such as ascii text or numbers.

You error must be somewhere else but it's impossible to tell because you didn't provide enough information.

What is the encoding that you are using (UTF-8 or something else) and what happens if you change the overall direction of the page in the settings of the browser?

Comment: The example in the question can not be re-created with just the snippet of CSS provided. [This example](http://jsbin.com/siyara/1/edit) does not have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very good at Arabic however believe that the `direction: rtl;` is going to be your problem as it reverses the text so it is backwards

Comment: The example in the question can not be re-created with just the snippet of CSS provided. [This example](http://jsbin.com/siyara/1/edit) does not have the issue.